# How to Prevent whole page post back while updating update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm trying to do an asp 4.0 website which shows videos in an page.i wrote code to display the videos and used update panel to refresh the content every 10sec.but the whole page is posting back.
Here is my code.

```
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>       

          <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
             <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>

             <ItemTemplate>
            <table border="1" align="left">
                  <tr><td>
               <div  style="float:left;">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"
            Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                       <div style="background: 
            url(http://www.dollarshaveclub.com/skin/frontend/dsc-test/dsc-
            theme/images/video_placeholder.png) no-repeat; padding: 0px; width: 100px; 
            height: 70px;"></div>
            <br /><asp:LinkButton Text="View" ID="remove" runat="server" 
            ImageUrl="images/remove.png" CommandName="remove" UseSubmitBehavior="False" 
            /><br />
            <span class="projectboldtxt"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,                  
           "video_caption") %></span>
                         <span class="projectboldtxt"><%# 
            DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "video_date") %></span>
                        </div>
                                </td></tr>
                                </table>
                        </ItemTemplate>

                        <FooterTemplate><br /></FooterTemplate>

                        </asp:Repeater>


                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>

                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

c# code is as below

```
    dbOperation db = new dbOperation();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            SqlDataReader dr = db.ExRdr("Select * from video");
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                Repeater1.DataSource = dr;
                Repeater1.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                Lbl_error.Text = "No data found.";
            }
            db.ConClose();
        }
    }
```

code for timer

```
    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataReader dr = db.ExRdr("Select * from video");
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            Repeater1.DataSource = dr;
            Repeater1.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            Lbl_error.Text = "No data found.";
        }
        db.ConClose();
        UpdatePanel1.Update();
    }
```

My Question Is: How to Prevent whole page post back while updating update panel ??

Comment: Evolve to MVC/Web API with proper APIs for JS consumption or stay stuck with full page refresh. It's an inherent design limitation of classic ASP.Net AFAIK.

Comment: Can you show where the UpdatePanel begins? Is the Timer inside of the UpdatePanel?

Comment: I have placed the timer and tool script manager outside the update panel.The full is shown as your request @Daniel Sanchez

Comment: @Machinarius No, Web Forms is capable of sending data to/from the server without a post back. Using AJAX directly or via an UpdatePanel will do the trick.

Comment: @mason as you can see i've tried that too

Comment: You're touching on the problem with AJAX UpdatePanels: http://encosia.com/why-aspnet-ajax-updatepanels-are-dangerous/

Comment: Some body pls try to help me out this situation

Comment: @mason Writing a custom IHTTPHandler could be a way, but it seems like way too much effort

Answer (score 0):

Your `UpdatePanel` has an end tag inside the `ItemTemplate`, but its start tag is missing.